# Report View sorting DateTime column

Tags: reportviewer

How can I sort data in ReportView by column containing datetime

In rdlc file I have placed Table where I have 
in 1 column in Details `=Fields!StartTime` and in Header I set Interactive Sort with sort
expression : `=Fields!StartTime`

in 2 column I check if the field contains date `=IsDate(Fields!StartTime)`

When I execute it second column contains all true but it still don't sort properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

function `IsDate` recognize `Fields!StartTime` as date but it still sorts it as string
changing sorting expression to `=CDate(Fields!StartTime)` worked

Answer (score 0):

My problem was similar. I had `to_char` function on date in the sql query and interactive sorting was using the date as a string.

After removing `to_char` in the query sorting worked correcty.